# SQL query to find any products that appear on all orders

Tags: sql

From the SQL database tables *Products*, *Orders*, and *OrderDetails* (see ERD below), I want to find if any products appear on all orders.

This is question #4 in the section on *Many-to-Many Relationships* at https://www.richardtwatson.com/open/private/ClassicModels.html, as well as Exercise #14 at https://jovian.com/aakashns/advanced-sql-aggregation-and-joins.

A solution is provided:

```
-- Are there any products that appear on all orders?

SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM Orders
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
     SELECT * FROM OrderDetails
     WHERE Products.productCode = OrderDetails.productCode
     AND Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber
   )
);
```

The solution does work to find any products that appear on all orders, but I don't understand the logic which uses the two sub queries with `NOT EXISTS`.

[image]

References:

1. https://www.richardtwatson.com/open/private/ClassicModels.html
2. https://jovian.com/aakashns/advanced-sql-aggregation-and-joins

Comment: It seems to me this query returns all products that never appear on an order.

Comment: SQL is not a database, it is a language. Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: When in doubt - TEST IT -  see https://dbfiddle.uk/I7ql7ltq The given solution does identify any product that appears on every order, but the logic of the query is probably not obvious. Consider that both uses of `EXISTS`  require a correlation to "outer tables" (Products & Orders) and that these correlations are "nested" which will cause every product to be considered against every order, and then any product not mentioned on an order gets excluded because of the `NOT` conditions, which means that the only product rows that can be returned must appear on every order.

Comment: btw: the use of dual `NOT EXISTS` is also efficient. Whilst there are alternative methods for finding any product that is on every order - the alternatives are more "expensive" see:   
 https://dbfiddle.uk/v-lG_pCO

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Thank you for the verification and explanation! I'll try to get this question reopened so that you can be credited with your answer..

Comment: @PaulMaxwell My question was re-opened. Please submit your response as a formal answer so that you can get credit for the great help you've provided.  Thanks much!

Comment: Thanks, I thought it an interesting question that deserves an answer - I hope I've done it justice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution **does identify any product that appears on every order**, but the logic of the query is probably not obvious.

Consider that both uses of `EXISTS` require a correlation to "outer tables" (Products & Orders) and that these correlations are "nested" which will cause every product to be considered against every order (a "Cartesian product") hence all combinations of Product & Order are considered.

Then, any product not listed on an order gets excluded because of the `NOT` conditions, which ultimately means that the only product rows that can be returned must appear on every order.

It is possible to demonstrate this using the following sample data, plus if we compare the given solution to an alternative approach to list any products on all orders, we find that using the nested `not exists` approach is also comparatively more efficient. (nb: Postgres used for this example.)

```
INSERT INTO Products (productCode, productName, productDescription)
VALUES (1, 'Product A', 'This is product A.'),
       (2, 'Product B', 'This is product B.'),
       (3, 'Product C', 'This is product C.'),
       (4, 'Product D', 'This is product D.'),
       (5, 'Product E', 'This is product E.'),
       (6, 'Product F', 'This is product F.')


INSERT INTO Orders (orderNumber, orderDate)
VALUES (1001, '2021-01-01'),
       (1002, '2021-02-15'),
       (1003, '2021-03-10');

/* NB product 1 appears on EVERY order */
INSERT INTO OrderDetails (orderNumber, productCode, quantity)
VALUES (1001, 1, 10),
       (1001, 2, 5),
       (1002, 1, 2),
       (1002, 3, 7),
       (1003, 1, 3),
       (1003, 2, 3),
       (1003, 4, 4);
```

In this data productCode 1 is present on all 3 orders.

Now, running the given solution:

```
SELECT * FROM Products
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT * FROM Orders
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (
     SELECT * FROM OrderDetails
     WHERE Products.productCode = OrderDetails.productCode
     AND Orders.orderNumber = OrderDetails.orderNumber
   )
);
```

**result:**

| productcode | productname | productdescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A | This is product A. |

It is possible to use an alternative approach as a solution, like this:

```
SELECT Products.productCode, COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.orderNumber) AS numOrders
FROM Products
JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.productCode = OrderDetails.productCode
JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.orderNumber = Orders.orderNumber
GROUP BY Products.productCode
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.orderNumber) = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Orders
        );
```

**result:**

| productcode | numorders |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |

**However** the explain plans of each demonstrate that the dual/nested use of `NOT EXISTS` is quite efficient:

```
| QUERY PLAN 1 (not exists)|
|:-------------------------|
| Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.00..1110917.22 rows=60 width=638) |
|   Join Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) |
|   ->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..11.20 rows=120 width=638) |
|   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..43.90 rows=2260 width=4) |
|         ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) |
|   SubPlan 2 |
|     ->  Seq Scan on orderdetails  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=8) |


| QUERY PLAN 2 (grouping) |
|:------------------------|
| GroupAggregate  (cost=213.68..224.36 rows=1 width=646) |
|   Group Key: products.productcode |
|   Filter: (count(DISTINCT orders.ordernumber) = $0) |
|   InitPlan 1 (returns $0) |
|     ->  Aggregate  (cost=38.25..38.26 rows=1 width=8) |
|           ->  Seq Scan on orders orders\_1  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=0) |
|   ->  Sort  (cost=175.42..178.48 rows=1224 width=642) |
|         Sort Key: products.productcode |
|         ->  Hash Join  (cost=73.55..112.64 rows=1224 width=642) |
|               Hash Cond: (orderdetails.ordernumber = orders.ordernumber) |
|               ->  Hash Join  (cost=12.70..48.57 rows=1224 width=642) |
|                     Hash Cond: (orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode) |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on orderdetails  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=8) |
|                     ->  Hash  (cost=11.20..11.20 rows=120 width=638) |
|                           ->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..11.20 rows=120 width=638) |
|               ->  Hash  (cost=32.60..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) |
```

note the sample size is tiny of course and there are no indexes, but notwithstanding the second explain requires more steps.

See this demonstrated here: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/v-lG_pCO)